# How to use dropzone JS for some button on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few buttons on the page. I need to load file when I click on each of buttons.

Every button has unique `data-id` attribute, which I must to pass in request AJAX, when I click it.

How can I do this using [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) plugin?

Comment: I can not see sample in documentation

Comment: are you saying that you want buttons instead of a dropzone?

Comment: Yes, I mean links `a` with `btn` bootsratp class

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood, sorry. Would be open to using something else? Dropzone doesn't do this AFAIK, but I once needed the same thing so I wrote a JS lib to do it. Would that be an acceptable answer?

Comment: I won't answer then, but you can [look at this](https://github.com/Pamblam/fileUpload). /It does exactly what you need.

Comment: What do you mean? I repeat again that there are some links ot buttons with attribute, clicking that I need to load file

Comment: Sorry, I did not see link above. You offer to use another library?

Comment: Yes I do. Is that acceptable? If you're ok with that I can add an answer with more details. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8c8wo53v/

Comment: Yes, post this as answer with some buttons and different `data-id` attribute. I want to see how to transfer `data-id` in request to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is an example of how you can create a button that will upload a file and a data attribute with Bootstrap.

```
<button class='btn btn-default chooser' data-id='hello'>Choose a file</button>
```

The JS requires this helper library I wrote for this exact purpose: [fileUpload.js](https://github.com/Pamblam/fileUpload)

```
$(".chooser").each(function() {
    var ele = this;
    $(ele).fileUpload({
        change: function() {
            // Get the files from the input
            var files = $(ele).fileUpload("getFiles");
            var formData = new FormData();
            for (var i = files.length; i--;)
                formData.append('myFiles[]', self.files[i], self.files[i].name);
            // Get the data attribute from the button
            formData.append('data-id', $(ele).data('id'));
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://mywebsite.com/uploads",
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
            }).always(function(xhr) {
                // all done. do something with the response here
            });
        }
    });
});
```

There are other options, you can restrict it to only accept certain file types or multiple files, etc. See the link above for more info.

Comment: You use `id`, so ig I have 100 buttons, I should to duplicate your code every time

Comment: @MisterPi - This is just an example. You can just as easily use classes.

Comment: Okay, then how to get data-id attribute in this event?

Comment: @MisterPi - bro, i explained the code in the comments. Did you read it? 8th ilne down `$("#chooser").data('id')` returns the data-id attribute.

Comment: @MisterPi - I edited the code to show you how to do it with classes. If that is what you were looking for please remember to hit the checkmark by the answer.